# Lubuntu/LXDE Desktop Configuration Files/Desktop Shortcuts

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

Novice problem:

I'm running Lubuntu and on my desktop I've created (mangled) two shortcuts...

I created them by right-clicking on the desktop and selecting Create New... > Shortcut

If I try to rename them, the first one is named "TeamSpeak", but appears as "TeamSpeak Server" when normally viewed from the desktop, and the second one is named "A" but appears as "TeamSpeak" when normally viewed from the desktop.

After goofing around trying to make a script to fix mouse settings using a text file on the desktop, I can no longer summon the shortcut editor, nor open them in a text editor. For some reason, they are set to open with Leafpad, but even then, nothing happens on double-click.

The shortcuts were supposed to run shell scripts, and I never got them to work before breaking them even more.

Running the shell scripts from the command line works fine.

How do I get working shortcuts (to shell scripts) in Lubuntu/LXDE?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to do and how you reached the point of having `desktop shortcuts`. I'm asking because I think `desktop shortcuts` aren't there by default. Are you also saying that you can't edit anything in `/usr/share/applications`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to edit the .desktop file with Leafpad. If you can't open it clicking it with mouse second button, you can try it from terminal.

An example of a shortcut that launchs a shell script, viewed here: http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=31647&f=8

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Nix
Comment=RunNixNote
Icon=/home/username/.extra-icons/Nevernote-164x308.png
Exec=sh /usr/share/nixnote/nixnote.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```