# Shell script does not run when I double click

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, scripts, 15.04

I have made a shell script (test.sh) on my Lubuntu (15.04) desktop.
Permissions are: Only owner (View content + Change content + Execute).

When I double click test.sh, I choose "Execute in Terminal".
The Terminal (LXTerminal) opens, but the script is not executed.

When I type `./test.sh` the script is executed.  But that is not what I want.
Solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your script lacks a shebang line. Make sure the very first line of the script reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

On a side note, you should avoid putting `.sh` extension on a bash script, since bash is not sh. Preferably use no extension at all.

Comment: +1. I disagree about the .sh part, but the rest seems right.

Comment: @Tim, `.sh` suggests it is an sh script, which is misleading since it's a bash script. Also see http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful

Comment: Does that apply to .js, .php, .html as well or really just bash files?

Comment: @tim, yes if they are commands (that have shebangs and are meant to be executed). So .html does not apply.

Comment: If the script successfully executes when `./test.sh` is executed from the terminal, wouldn't it already have to have a shebang line?

Comment: @drkokandy. bash is being "helpful" and decides to execute it with bash if execve(2) fails. When running it directly with a terminal, there's no "helpful shell".

Comment: If using .sh implies it's an sh script, then why wouldn't people use .bash for a bash script?  .sh means it's a shell script, and bash is a shell.  I think using .sh is just a matter of preference, and a very good case can be made for using it, if desired.

Comment: @MartyFried, for a bash script meant to be sourced, adding `.bash` extension is a good idea. For commands, it's useless information. Most users don't care what language a command is written in as long as it does what it's supposed to do. If users did care, you'd be running `ls.elf64` rather than `ls` to list the files of a directory. I know crappy tutorials, guides and scripts around the net use `.sh` extensions on bash scripts. That doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: my .sh file starts with `#!/bin/bash` but double click still doesn't work. And that is the proper path to the bash shell.

Comment: I needed to go to Files > Preferences and setup to run executable files on double click. Insted of viewing them.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a known, existing bug: [lubuntu-default-settings does not specify the proper command to execute in terminal](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/975152)

That bug report suggests the following workaround (using X-terminal instead.)

> WORKAROUND:
>
> In pcmanfm preferences, under the advanced tab, change the terminal to `"x-terminal-emulator -e %s"`. You can also change the "terminal" value in ~/.config/libfm/libfm.conf.

An alternative workaround I've used before is creating a desktop shortcut - but then you're limited to only being able to double-click on the desktop.

To create a shortcut, you can run the command:

`lxshortcut -o ~/Desktop/test.sh`

(Where test.sh is the name you want the file to have on the desktop.)

This will open lxshortcut, which will create a .desktop file from your responses in a GUI.

[Manually creating a .desktop file should also work](https://askubuntu.com/a/306522/103537).